# place row at bottom of container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

been struggling with this layout, mainly trying to find a solution that works cross browser and is responsive.  I am aiming for a layout like so

[image: Layout]

Essentially, I have a menu at the top which is 120px high.  This is fixed.  I then have the main header section which should have a `min-height:100vh;`.  Within this, on the left, I have some text which should be vertically aligned within the middle of the section.  I then have an image which should be at the bottom of the section, as well as horizontally in the middle.

I came up with the following structure

```
<header id="top-area">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="headings">
                    <h1>Some Title</h1>
                    <p>Some Text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="http://www.atfund.gatech.edu/sites/default/files/images/verticalplaceholderimage-440x680.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

So I let both the text and the image take up 4 columns.  This should allow the image to be in the center of the screen.

So, I started the CSS like so

```
#top-area {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 120px; //for the menu
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

so I set the height, give it a padding to allow for the menu, and then a few additional things.  I have tried so many things to get the rest of the layout in place, trying to keep in mind that it needs to collapse nicely for mobile.  I am now trying flex.

Whatever I try, it seems that I have to actually give it a height (not min-height) of 100vh, which then causes things to be too small on other devices, or I need to give it an absolute position which then takes it out of the flow of the document.

I have provided a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z69w9u4g/30/) to demonstrate where I am at, but it is a bit messy at the moment as I have been trying many different approaches.

What is the best way to achieve this layout, whilst taking into account different browsers and responsiveness?

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good idea to use `justify-content:space-between`, but you need at the minimum 2 children, first one can be generated via `::before` or an empty tag and be used to save your 120px for the `fixed` menu.

bootstrap-4 has a few [class dedicated to the flex model](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/), you may use them and create only the one that are missing to your needs :

**example to test full page** 
*(your fiddle is linked to bootstrap-4 beta, so is the snippet)*

```css
#top-area {
  background: #ccc;
}

.mn120 {/* custom class */
  min-height: 120px;
}

.mh100vh {/* custom class */
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.headings {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 25% 0 30%;
}

#top-area .row {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#top-area h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.25;
  letter-spacing: -0.5px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#top-area p {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.33;
  letter-spacing: -0.2px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#top-area img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header id="top-area">
  <div class="container d-flex flex-column justify-content-between fHeight mh100vh">
    <div class="mn120">
      <!-- this can be generated via a pseudo ::before to be laid ubder fixed menu -->
    </div>
    <div class="row  d-flex fHeight">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="headings">
          <h1>Some Title</h1>
          <p>Some Text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="http://www.atfund.gatech.edu/sites/default/files/images/verticalplaceholderimage-440x680.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it works perfectly.  I had one more question.  I have another section which is similar.  However, the bottom row contains two images, which are different sizes.  When I do the above, the smaller image sits at the top of the column, instead of at the bottom.  Is there any class too get it too the bottom?  Thanks

Comment: @kate_hudson . do you have an example ? is there more than 2 direct childen ? this example here uses the empty element to sit at the top edge, the second stands at bottom on the other edge.

Comment: for the other section, you can use this again : `<div class="container d-flex flex-column justify-content-between fHeight mh100vh">
    <div class="mn120">
      <!-- this can be generated via a pseudo ::before to be laid ubder fixed menu -->
    </div>
    <div class="row  d-flex fHeight"><!--- content of row to sit at bottom--></div>
  </div>`

Comment: Sure, I created this https://jsfiddle.net/z69w9u4g/33/ so you can see that the smaller image is not sitting at the bottom of the row

Comment: @kate_hudson you can add margin-top:auto to .col-md-4 or use align-items-end class on .row https://jsfiddle.net/z69w9u4g/35/ https://jsfiddle.net/z69w9u4g/36/